# How to disable edittext pop up when EditText is LongClicked?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hello All I have used `onLongClickListener()` to my `EditText` view but whenever I click on view for long time so a popup appears that doesn't let me do my task in `onLongClick(View v)`.
The pop up contains some options like Select All,Select Text,Cut All ,Copy All etc.
I want to disable that (that should not appear on clicking long on EditText view).
How can I do that please Help Me

Comment: How about only showing the popup on finger release, and when finger has been held down < 1000 ms, or whatever is the time required for longclick.

Comment: Have u overridden tat method..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can return true in your onLongClick listener onLongClick method that means you have consumed the event and it won't be passed further along.

Comment: popup also opens up when you double click on edit text. How to handle that ?

Answer (score 1):

I also got that popup when I overrode onTouchEvent() and returned false.  Suppress it by returning true.