# EditText onLongClick(); hiding cut/copy/selectall bar

Tags: android, android-edittext, onlongclicklistener

when you long click an editText in andriod, a utility bar with options to cut/copy/select all/select word comes up.  I am using an onLongClickListener to bring up an Dialog- and want to hide these edit options.

i'm not sure what it is called, so i cant find it in any documentation in order to figure out how to hide it.

i'd like something that does this:

```
onLongClick(View v){
//hide edit options
myDialogBox.show();
}
```

Comment: did you try to return true in your onLongClick(View v) implementation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return `true` in your `onLongClick()`-method so the Android Framework knows that the action has been consumed.

Further information can be found here: [How to disable edittext pop up when EditText is LongClicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435662/how-to-disable-edittext-pop-up-when-edittext-is-longclicked)